# Saving information to mysql in multiple tables

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am trying to get information to be saved in one database into 5 tables from user input.
There are no errors that pop-up but the data won't save to the DB. Any sample code or typed solutions would be great. Thanks.

Here is my code so far:
The arrays are defined on a different page.

```
$array = array("example");
$random = $array;
shuffle($random);
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
<form action="Voting_action.php" method="post">
<td><input type="image" value="<?php echo $img;?>" /> 
<input type="submit"class="buttontable1" value="<?php echo array_pop($random);?>" name="name"/></td>
<td><input type="image" value="<?php echo $img;?>" />
<input type="submit" class="buttontable2" value="<?php echo array_pop($random2);?>" name="name2" /></td>
</form>
</tr>

<tr>
<form action="Voting_action.php" method="post">
<td><input type="image" value="<?php echo $img;?>" />
<input type="submit" class="buttontable1" value="<?php echo array_pop($random3);?>" name="name3"/></td>
<td><input type="image" value="<?php echo $img;?>" />
<input type="submit" class="buttontable2" value="<?php echo array_pop($random4);?>" name="name4" /></td>
</form>
</tr>

<tr>
<form action="Voting_action.php" method="post">
<td><input type="image" value="<?php echo $img;?>" />
<input type="submit" class="buttontable1" value="<?php echo array_pop($random);?>" name="name"/></td>
<td><input type="image" value="<?php echo $img;?>" />
<input type="submit" class="buttontable2" value="<?php echo array_pop($random5);?>" name="name5" /></td>
</form>
</tr>
```

Here's the PHP mysqli code I have so far with some help from other tutorials and forums:

```
<?php
include('Voting.php');
$server = '';
$dbname= '';
$username = '';
$password = '';


$link = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
header('Location: /errordocs/500.php');
exit;
}

$link->autocommit(FALSE);


$sql = "INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES (?)";

if ($stmt = $link->prepare($sql)) {
  $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $array);
  $stmt->execute();

$firstinsert = $stmt->affected_rows;
 }
$stmt->close;

$newid = $link->insert_id;

$sql = "INSERT INTO table(name2) VALUES (?)";

if ($stmt = $link->prepare($sql)) {
  $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $array2);
  $stmt->execute();

$secondinsert = $stmt->affected_rows;
 }
$stmt->close;

$newid = $link->insert_id;

$sql = "INSERT INTO table(name3) VALUES (?)";

if ($stmt = $link->prepare($sql)) {
  $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $array3);
  $stmt->execute();


$thirdinsert = $stmt->affected_rows;
 }
$stmt->close;

$newid = $link->insert_id;


$sql = "INSERT INTO table(name4) VALUES (?)";

if ($stmt = $link->prepare($sql)) {
  $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $array4);
  $stmt->execute();

$fourthinsert = $stmt->affected_rows;
 }
$stmt->close;

$newid = $link->insert_id;

$sql = "INSERT INTO table(name5) VALUES (?)";

if ($stmt = $link->prepare($sql)) {
  $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $array5);
  $stmt->execute();


$fifthinsert = $stmt->affected_rows;
 }
$stmt->close;


if (($firstinsert == 1) && ($secondinsert == 1) && ($thirdinsert == 1) && ($fourthinsert == 1) && ($fifthinsert == 1)) {

$link->commit();
$link->autocommit(TRUE);
  return 1;
 } else {
$link->rollback();
$link->autocommit(TRUE);
  return 0;
 }
?>
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: From what it looks like in your `bind_param`, you are trying to bind more parameters than you have in the statement.  Also, where are `$array`, `$array2`, etc being defined, or are they truly arrays of one element.  If they have multiple elements that you then shuffle, that would also cause errors in the insert statements.

Comment: Yes, I have it setup to where the arrays are defined then shuffled then ran through the bind_param and they have many elements. how should I go about changing the parameters?

Comment: Some of your binds, are `ssi`, meaning two strings and an integer, if you shuffle the array, `bind_param` won't work, or type-cast your value unexpectedly. (also, your statements don't allow for multiple parameters to be bound either.)

Comment: Thank you. One more thing. If I had 400+ elements in the array would I put 400 "s"'s?

Comment: If you need to insert 400+ elements in to one row of a table, then the table is designed poorly.  But theoretically, yes, you would need 400 `s`'s in the `bind_param`, (or a `foreach` loop binding them individually. (which, honestly, shouldn't be done) )

Comment: Thank you for the prompt responses your awesome!

Comment: Sorry about asking so many questions but would function writeClient($array, $array2, $array3, $array4, $array5) bind the parameters?

Comment: I don't know of the function `writeClient` is it a function that you wrote?  Just from what you show defining it, I can't say if it would or not - though mostly likely not as the `statement` variable wouldn't be available in there unless you `global` it, though that wouldn't be suggested. ^^